# Capturing screen output to file with expect module on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I need capture the screen output of a particular command out the many commands that I am executing with an Expect script . The script works perfectly well without the capturing the output of that command , however it does not serve the purpose then .

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f
set systemTime [clock seconds]
set now [clock format $systemTime -format  "%m_%d_%y"]
exec touch ASR$now.txt
set Password "prizer"
set password "banger"
set bye "exit"
set quitconsole "q"
set exitcons "logout"
spawn  ssh admin@192.168.95.96
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
sleep 5
expect "admin>"
send "32\r"
sleep 5
send "\r"
expect "ASR1001>"
send "enable\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$Password\r"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "terminal length 0\r"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "show run \r"
set output [open "ASR$now.txt" "w"] **<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Fails here** 
send "$bye\r"
sleep 5
send "ctrl-]"
sleep 5
send "$quitconsole\r"
expect "admin>"
send "$exitcons\r"
expect eof
```

I would also like to know how to execute an expect script  with conditional statements as in
execute a list of commands only if the output of a certain command is negative or . Which would be similar to doing a grep and than executing the script further with if,else or while statements .

Thanks
Avinash

Answer (score 0):

We can capture the screen outputs in Unix / Linux terminals using **script** command 
The usage of the command is explained clearly [here](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~gini/1901-07s/files/script.html)

Comment: Yes that would work but only on a Linux system , I am using an expect script here and that too via a terminal server console port where the script command creates unnecessary clutter . I would need to use the SED command to clear out this clutter which I do not wish to do .

Comment: I could also use the "tee" command or the ">" command but that is only for Linux . this is expect .